# CW Complex Structure on union of circles

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have the following Question,

Consider the following subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. X is union of circles with radius $1/2^n$ and center $(1/2^n,0)$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Show with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$, X can not have a CW Complex structure in which $0$-cell is the origin and the $1$-cell are the circles.

I have read the definition of CW complex, Intuitively they are space built inductively by attaching $n-$ cells.

Comment: Hint: CW-complexes are locally contractible (you may need to prove this).

Comment: Alternately: any compact subspace of a CW complex can only intersect (the interiors of) finitely many cells, and the fundamental group of a finite CW complex is finitely generated.